# Android Development for Tablets

Tags: android, tablet

I am new to Android Development. Could you please suggest some resources (ebooks, blogs, tutorials....) for me to refer about Android app development for Tablets ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now in android Programming in Phone and tablet is almost same .and there are many tutorials available on net .there is one where i learn from is Markana bootcamp 
just search on youtube .and u will find your request

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply:

[Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

The Android training will take you through everything, from setting up your environment for programming in, right through to more complex things.

There is no difference between phone and tablet development.

I have an app designed to target both. There has been no change in code. You could potentially have custom layouts, but its usually not necessary. The code would still all be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to begin in my opinion is the [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html) by Google.  And there are some small differences in phone and tablet development components..(i.e. fragments were designed primarily to be used with tablets I believe), but the methodologies are largely identical.